# How do you translate these 2 regular languages in words correctly?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

Given are 2 different languages and I'd like to know if I understand them correctly.

L ⊆ ∑* is a regular language.

1. cycle(L) = {vu ∈ ∑* | uv ∈ L}
2. L/2 = {x ∈ ∑* | ∃y ∈ ∑* : xy ∈ L, |x| = |y|}

I need to know that because the actual task is to show that these languages are regular by either describing how you build a DFA or NFA for them.

But I just like to know if I understood them correctly.

---

So 1. means that every word has an existing reverse.

As example we have word `aaa` and `bab`, if we concatenate them, we have `aaabab`. Now the language says that there is also a word `babaaa`

2. Means that we have two words of same length and we concatenate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1. it is not quite the reverse; it happened to be a reverse in your example. So if $u = aab$ and $v = abb$ and $uv \in L$, then you know $vu = abbaab \in \text{cycle}(L)$, but you wouldn't be able to say that $bbabaa = v^Ru^R \in \text{cycle}(L)$.

For 2. it is not that you want the concatenation of two strings of equal length, but rather you only want the first half of even-length strings in $L$. That is, if, say, $aabbabbabb \in L$, then $aabba \in L/2$.